# Is it good to have a normal map on a subdivided model?

Tags: rendering, animation

When animating a head, it is quite usual to work with the original geometry and at the same time having a normal map on it. So, is this a good way of doing it:

You unwrap the head (lets call it "A"). You duplicate it two times ("B" and "C"). "A" has a subdivision surface modifier set on 1. "B" is the same as "A", but the modifier is applied. "C" is the high poly model to be used for baking a normal map on "B". However, the normal map is baked from "C" on "B" but it is used on "A", so that when you animate the head you work with the original geometry. My concern is - If you render an image, will the normal map fit on "A" the same way as on "B"? And what are some other ways of making a normal map for a model to be used for animation?

Again - 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually a normal map is used to create the illusion of detail when used on a lower poly model.  I'm unaware of any  reason to use one on a model that has the same vertex detail as the one you baked it from.

Comment: I'm not sure if the UVs on model A is the same as on model B because on model B the modifier is applied. That's why I asked "will the normal map fit on A the same way as on B?". Thanks for the response.

Comment: gotcha, that is a problem, some modifiers like Bevel will ruin the UV's, some like Sub-D or Multi-res should be fine so long as you get the 'Subdivide-UV's' set right for that particular model.  You'll just have to try and see what works when it comes to this.  If you keep the UV Image Editor open then you can always keep watch over what is happening with the UV islands.  Just remember there are 2 settings that can make the difference here.  UV Sync Selection makes it easy to see the UV's but it more difficult to alter the islands so try to get used to working with it both on and off.

Comment: I've also recently found that if a duplicate a low poly model and then add a bevel modifier to the second model and use that model to bake, the baked texture will work beautifully on the low-poly model that has no bevel modifier.  Just make sure not to apply that modifier or it will trash the UV's.  So long as it is still a modifier then it should work fine for baking.